# What is the most efficient way to make an iterator from a set returned by a function?

Tags: python, memory, iterator, set

I have recently starting working with iterators, and I have a little uncertainty about what is the right way to tackle the following problem (or whether it is a problem at all :)).

Let's say I have an `input_set` that is rather large, I want to generate an `intermediary_set` (or whatever iterable), that will be even larger. However, the latter will only be used once in a `for` loop later in the code.
So, I thought I should make a generator function that would take the `input_set` as parameter, apply the appropriate operations to obtain `intermediary_set`, and loop over it with a `yield` statement.

For instance:

```
def make_a_generator(input_set):
    intermediary_set = some_operations(input_set)
    for i in intermediary_set:
        yield i
```

One issue is that **some_operations()** involve some set operations, so that it is not possible to make a generator directly from looping over the `input_set`.

Alternatively I thought I could do:

```
iterator = (i for i in some_operations(input_set))
```

But I wonder if there is a better way, or another more efficient if `intermediary_set` is very large.

Comment: From your description `some_operations(input_set)` is creating the entire list of items.  That kills your objective of not generating all the items at once.  You would need `some_operations` to be a generator.

Comment: `iterator = iter(collection)` is the most efficient.